# Not authorized when trying to list milestones in gitlab ci

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I'm trying to list milestones in the gitlab ci script.

I want to create summary and deploy it together with other artifacts.

But I get the message I'm not authorized:

> $ curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_JWT"
> "$CI_SERVER_URL/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/milestones"   % Total
> % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
> Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100    30  100    30    0     0    346      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
> --:--:--   348 {"message":"401 Unauthorized"}

How should I use job token (or what to use instead) to access the milestones?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the predefined variable `CI_JOB_TOKEN` instead of `CI_JOB_JWT`. According to [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) for Predefined variables, `CI_JOB_JWT` tokens are used to authenticate with third party systems that support JWT authentication, for example HashiCorp’s Vault with a A RS256 JSON web token.

In contrast, `CI_JOB_TOKEN` is a token to authenticate with certain API endpoints. The token is valid as long as the job is running.

Otherwise, you could generate a Personal Access token for a Gitlab User, store it as a Project Variable in the project's CI/CD settings, and use it that way.